# Automatic Page Repair without AlwaysOn or Mirroring

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, availability-groups

Do Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Enterprise regular databases (without AlwaysOn) have Automatic Page Repair in any manner?

I know from below, by incorporating AlwaysOn, Secondary replicas receive Automatic Page repair. Just inquiring if this feature is available to SQL Server databases without Alwayson?

Per MSDN documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/overview-of-always-on-availability-groups-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017 , it states

"Each availability replica tries to automatically recover from corrupted pages on a local database by resolving certain types of errors that prevent reading a data page. If a secondary replica cannot read a page, the replica requests a fresh copy of the page from the primary replica. If the primary replica cannot read a page, the replica broadcasts a request for a fresh copy to all the secondary replicas and gets the page from the first to respond"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, if the database participates in Database Mirroring.

But otherwise, no. If you want page repair, you'll need to [do it manually with page level restores](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/restore-pages-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: Just to clarify, page repair isn't "available to" mirror or secondary. The reason automatic page repair can work is that there is still an un-broken page in the secondary *before* the broken page from the primary has been copied over. The process doesn't fix the secondary, the process takes the still-good page from the secondary and applies it to the primary, replacing the broken page there. If you don't have a secondary (e.g. you're not using mirroring or AGs), you have to go get the page yourself, as the link describes.